# Convert PowerShell object to string

Tags: string, powershell, psobject

I am pulling data from a web service and want to convert the object data into a string.

I am calling using:

```
$URI = "http://siteURL"
$Con = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $URI -namespace WebServiceProxy -class Nlyte
$WebCon= $con.GetData('Server')
$OpenCon = [xml] $WebCon
```

I then query the data:

```
$OpenCon.Response.Server | Where-Object {$_.AssetID -eq 8186} | Select Asset_x0020_Name
```

The data comes back as so:

```
Asset_x0020_Name
----------------
SERVERNAME4001
```

How can I now take that object data and turn into into a string?

Answer (score 3):

This may be used:

```
$OpenCon.Response.Server | Where-Object {$_.AssetID -eq 8186} | Select -ExpandProperty Asset_x0020_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided a different approach is the simplest way to go.
Instead of trying to convert the individual object values to a string I just put the entire object into a variable and call each value from there.

```
$Server = $a.Response.Server | Where-Object {$_.AssetID -eq 8186}
$Server.Asset_x0020_Name
```

Comment: You can also do this: ($a.Response.Server | Where-Object {$_.AssetID -eq 8186}).Asset_x0020_Name